# How to access a page with and without springboot authentication?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have created a simple project using tutorials on `Springboot` and `mongodb`. Currently, I have a page like the following:
[image: first page]

As you see, it is a search page. Til yesterday, it did not include the search option and the user could just click on login and then search for something
If the user clicks on the `login` button and logs into the system, he can search for the items and the result is shown on a page called `searchResults.html` without any problem.
However, what I need to do is to let the use search at the first page (the page has been changed to the picture shown above to include the search option) and see the results. That is, there are two options: 1) The user logs into the system, searches the items and see the results and 2) The user searches something without logging into the system.
The current implemention current the first part, but not the second part. I don't know how I should change my implementation.
Here is the relevant code (if I should share other parts of the code, please let me know):

First page code:

```
    <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content">
            <h1>Welcome!</h1>
            <form action="/search" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-6" id="category_search">
<div class="dropdown">
                            <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                        id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
                                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select a category</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu1"
                                        aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="Hotel">Hotel</a> <a
                                            class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="Food">Fast food</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" id="search_city_id">
                    </div>  
                </div>   
                <div class="form-group row">   
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" name="search" id="search"
                            class="form-control coloredInput" th:value="${search}" />
                    </div>
    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="search">Search</button>
    
                </div>    
            </form>   
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my controller class:

```
@Controller
public class RController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userService;

    
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("pointList", rRepository.findAll());
        return "home";
    }

    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search")
    public ModelAndView search(Model model, @RequestParam("search") String search,
            @RequestParam ("search-entityType-value") String searchEntityTypeValue,
            @RequestParam("selected_category") String selected_category
            ) {

        List<RAggrResults> result = RSearchRepository.searchRs(search, searchEntityTypeValue, selected_category);

        
        LinkedHashMap<String, List<R>> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<R>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
             List<R> rs_of_one_group = result.get(i).getRs();
            
                hashMap.put(rs_of_one_group.get(0).getPlace().getPlace_name(), result.get(i).getRs());
            
        }

        model.addAttribute("searchResult", hashMap);
        model.addAttribute("search", search);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        modelAndView.addObject("currentUser", user);
        modelAndView.addObject("fullName", "Welcome " + user.getFullname());
        modelAndView.addObject("adminMessage", "Content Available Only for Users with Admin Role");

        modelAndView.setViewName("searchResults");

        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

And here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService mongoUserDetails() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = mongoUserDetails();
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.antMatchers("/search").permitAll()` and secendly check if user is logged in in controller before you add user details to view.

Comment: @Seldo97 Thanks a lot. It worked. Could you please write your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it as the correct answer?

Comment: No problem. I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set permition for your `/search` endpoint: `.antMatchers("/search").permitAll()`.
And secondly in your case I recommend to check if user is logged in in controller before you add user details to view.